# Nestled While loops?

Tags: php

I have a bit of code:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
    echo "['".$row['Month']."',".$row['Store A'].",".$row['Store B'].",".$row['Store C']."],";
```

Which works fine for cases when a user has Store A, B & C - however, I want to expand this to people who will have a varying amount of stores.

I know the array $Sat has headers, so, is it possible to count the headers and whilst they don't equal Month (Month needs to go first) echo out the header name so I feed the associated rows into the format I need for my next step.

The final output should look like `['Month',Store A,Store B,Store C]` (if the user had the three stores, or maybe `['Month',Store A,Store C]` if they had just A & C etc..

I've been trying to substitute the code with a variable that builds it but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm not very well experienced in PHP (or coding really) and just trying to adapt something to work internally at work a bit better and save my sanity = )

So, if my database was:

> ```
> +-------+---------+---------+---------+
> | Month | Store A | Store B | Store C |
> +-------+---------+---------+---------+
> | May-19|      0.0|      0.0|      0.0|
> | Jun-19|     12.5|      8.3|      0.0|
> | Jul-19|     10.5|     14.3|      0.0|
> +-------+---------+---------+---------+
> ```

The required output would be: `['May-19',0.0,0.0,0.0],['Jun-19',12.5,8.3,0.0],['Jul-19',10.5,14.3,0.0],` to feed into Google Charts.

Original SQL query is:

```php
$sql_prep = "SELECT d.store_list AS NUMB, s.name AS NAME FROM data d INNER JOIN store_list s ON d.store_list=s.store_id WHERE d.status != '' AND d.store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ") GROUP BY store_list";
$sql_code = $conn->query($sql_prep);
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
    $select = $select . "CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  '" . $row['NAME'] . "',";
}
....
$sql = "SELECT
    " . $select . "
    DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month'
FROM data 
WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";
```

which would compile to:

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  'Store A',
    CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  'Store B',
    CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  'Store C',
    DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month'
FROM data 
WHERE store_list IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC
```

and output:

> ```
> +---------+---------+---------+-------+
> | Store A | Store B | Store C | Month |
> +---------+---------+---------+-------+
> |      0.0|      0.0|      0.0| May-19|
> |     12.5|      8.3|      0.0| Jun-19|
> |     10.5|     14.3|      0.0| Jul-19|
> +---------+---------+---------+-------+
> ```

I've found I can edit my original code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
    echo "['".$row['Month']."',".$row['Store A'].",".$row['Store B'].",".$row['Store C']."],";
```

to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
    echo "['".$row['Month']."',".$row[0].",".$row[1].",".$row[2]."],";
```

So this get's around the naming, I just need to have in there as many rows as I have stores now, without building a giant "IF THEN" query. I still feel this is a nestled while or foreach that would do this?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need a nested loop -- the code you have above should simply omit `Store B` if it is not found for a particular row.

Comment: Make good use of JOIN SQL statement

Comment: @ObsidianAge the code would emit ['Month',Store A,,Store C] if the user didn't have Store B, which sadly makes the next part fail (a Google Chart, won't render), which is why I need to build what's in this based on the array (also, new stores could be added and I don't want to have to update every time that happens).
I've simplified the above with using 3 stores, they're 1.4k in the database and a user could have up to twenty (rare, but, could).

Comment: @Raptor thank you but the SQL running into this (which I am comfortable with) is already good, the issue is unknown store names & amount of stores when run for various users. Additionally the Google Chart uses these to name the axis, so I couldn't cheat with placeholders, Apologies, all info you weren't given.

I just need to iterate through the array and emit each store name, the SQL will return only month and storename as headers in the array, so that's safe to assume.

Comment: I think you want something like this:-`$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
 $array[$row['Month']]  = $row;
}

print_r($array);`

Comment: Dump the fetched array what you want to parse, we will help, by var_dump($row); die();

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie that outputs: 
`Array ( [May-19] => Array ( [0] => 0.0 [Store A] => 0.0 [1] => 0.0 [Store B] => 0.0 [2] => 0.0 [Store C] => 0.0 [3] => May-19 [Month] => May-19 ) [Jun-19] => Array ( [0] => 12.5 [Store A] => 12.5 [1] => 8.3 [Store B] => 8.3 [2] => 0.0 [Store C] => 0.0 [3] => Jun-19 [Month] => Jun-19 ) [Jul-19] => Array ( [0] => 10.5 [Store A] => 10.5 [1] => 14.3 [Store B] => 14.3 [2] => 0.0 [Store C] => 0.0 [3] => Jul-19 [Month] => Jul-19 ) )`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco that outputs: 
 `array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "0.0" ["Store A"]=> string(3) "0.0" [1]=> string(3) "0.0" ["Store B"]=> string(3) "0.0" [2]=> string(3) "0.0" ["Store C"]=> string(3) "0.0" [3]=> string(6) "May-19" ["Month"]=> string(6) "May-19" } `

Comment: I've edited in above how that would need to be echo'd out as to support the google chart. Thanks everyone for their advice this far!

Comment: @Sam post your SQL query pls

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco have edited in above for easier reading then the comments allow - thanks!

Comment: Could you post raw output, what you comment to me in proper format what you get right now, like a example. It is hard to see how the fetched arrays are composed. Thank you

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco have edited in above, thank you

Comment: I was talking about this `array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "0.0" ["Store A"]=> string(3) "0.0" [1]=> string(3) "0.0" ["Store B"]=> string(3) "0.0" [2]=> string(3) "0.0" ["Store C"]=> string(3) "0.0" [3]=> string(6) "May-19" ["Month"]=> string(6) "May-19" } `

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the final outcome i need for Google Charts? `['May-19',0.0,0.0,0.0],['Jun-19',12.5,8.3,0.0],['Jul-19',10.5,14.3,0.0],`

Comment: No, i mean what you get right now with your sql statement, It looks that you get some duplicate values. for each store.

Comment: Ah, no, the table I put at the end of the post is exactly what I get when I run it.

Comment: I guess you have wrong SQL query. It late right now i will try to help you tomorrow.

Comment: So, you do not know how many stores can user have right? it may be 3 and so on

Comment: One user could have three, the next five, then maybe twenty, it all depends on the user.

The SQL works when testing with a user of 3 stores using the updated code that returns the array item from it's position, rather than it's name, so they can have any 3 and it works, if a user has more or fewer though it will fail (as other parts of the google chart are expecting more or fewer stores), so I'm fairly confident of the SQL. I just need to build the output to match the format Google Chart needs.

Comment: Thank you for your time and assistance thus far, sleep well!

Comment: Just for clarity, in that "I don't know how many stores a user has" - I mean it's highly variable, I could do a quick check on their user table in the DB to find how many, if that helps build a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code below, i did found some type errors in sql syntax:

```
    $sql_prep = "SELECT d.store_list AS NUMB, s.name AS NAME FROM data d INNER JOIN store_list s ON d.store_list=s.store_id WHERE d.status != '' AND d.store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ") GROUP BY store_list";
$sql_code = $conn->query($sql_prep);
$select = '';
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $select .= ", CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  '" . $row['NAME'] . "' "; -- right here
    }
.....
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y') AS 'Month'
" . $select . "
FROM data 
WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";
```

Try this code, it suppose to produce this:

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| Month | Store A | Store B | Store C |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| May-19|      0.0|      0.0|      0.0|
| Jun-19|     12.5|      8.3|      0.0|
| Jul-19|     10.5|     14.3|      0.0|
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

with arrays:

```
['May-19',0.0,0.0,0.0],['Jun-19',12.5,8.3,0.0],['Jul-19',10.5,14.3,0.0]
```

to echo full array you need this:

```
$result = [];
$index = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){
    //we know for sure that index 0 has value Month, then..
    $temp = [$row['Month']];
    $number = count($row) - 1;
    //loop thru rest of rows start from index 1
    for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++){
        //push rows in to temporary array
        array_push($temp, $row[$i]);
    }
    //merge result in main array
    $result[$index] = $temp;
    $index++;
}
var_dump($result);
```

That's what i get:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'moth1' (length=5)
      1 => float 10
      2 => float 20
      3 => float 30.6
      4 => float 45.2
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'moth2' (length=5)
      1 => float 10
      2 => float 20
      3 => float 30.6
      4 => float 45.2
      5 => float 45.8
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'moth3' (length=5)
      1 => float 10
      2 => float 20
      3 => float 30.6
      4 => float 45.2
  3 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'moth4' (length=5)
      1 => float 10
      2 => float 20
      3 => float 30.6
      4 => float 45.2
      5 => float 56.2
      6 => float 56.3
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'moth5' (length=5)
      1 => float 10
      2 => float 20
      3 => float 30.6
      4 => float 45.2
```

tested data:

```
    $rows = [
       ['Month' => 'moth1', 10.0, 20.0, 30.6, 45.2],
       ['Month' => 'moth2', 10.0, 20.0, 30.6, 45.2, 45.8],
       ['Month' => 'moth3', 10.0, 20.0, 30.6, 45.2],
       ['Month' => 'moth4', 10.0, 20.0, 30.6, 45.2, 56.2, 56.3],
       ['Month' => 'moth5', 10.0, 20.0, 30.6, 45.2],
   ];
```

Comment: @Dharman  i agree with you, but in this case he gets calculated data from DB, and that was not in scope of this question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I'm missing something here, how do I echo this out for google charts? So far it looks like I still have to use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sat)){echo "['".$row['Month']."',".$row[1].",".$row[2].",".$row[3]."],"; }` which is the bit I'm trying to work around, so I don't have to define a $row[x] for each store as there's variable number of stores?

Comment: it is all depends on what array you need to echo? JSON or php?

Comment: I'm really sorry here and feel like a blithering idiot, but how does this get around defining `row[x]` so I can have N number of rows?

Comment: I just updated my answer, if that helps please feel free to rate my answer.

Comment: You have to take a look on PDO, and also consider to learn some new PhP frameworks like Yii2 or Laravel, Symfony ..ect., or Codigniter. It will give you a lot more flexibility and security when you working with DB.

Comment: Thanks for all your work on this, but all it's returning is NULL. I've tried tinkering around to work out what I could be implementing wrong but can't seem to find it = \

Comment: I did updated my answer, that was my mistake. but now should works good, i also posted an output from my test page.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/ohNwq3u.png) is what I get (source code of the rendered page), how do I collapse this down to `['May-19',0.0,0.0,0.0],['Jun-19',12.5,8.3,0.0],['Jul-19',10.5,14.3,0.0]` - I think it's the var_dump() structure.

Comment: That's because sql returs the max possible stores, the workaround with this will be to count how many user has stores and query that inside the loop, at the same time assign the result to array.

Comment: does my answer helps?

Comment: and also, on the image you provide, How you count how many can be possible stores? i guess you make a query. In this case we are good, that it will return the max stores available, and user will have on that stores 0 result

Comment: Thanks for you help with this @SergheiLeonenco - you gave me the idea below which has solved what I need today! Now to, as you and others say, make this more secure - there's no user input here (it's all read from the DB), so I don't think it's directly exploitable but, best to be using the better methods! = )

Comment: yep:) that's true

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!

Thanks to @Serghei Leonenco for talking this through, I used some of your ideas in building this, but this works exactly as needed for N stores. Cheers, couldn't've done it without you!

```
<?php
//dynamically build chart queries
$sql_prep = "SELECT d.store_list AS NUMB, s.name AS NAME FROM data d INNER JOIN store_list s ON d.store_list=s.store_id WHERE d.status != '' AND d.store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ") GROUP BY store_list";
$sql_code = $conn->query($sql_prep);
$select = '';
    while($row = $sql_code->fetch_assoc()) {
        $select .= ", CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(`q3`) = 'no' AND store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN store_list = " . $row['NUMB'] . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))*100) as decimal (10,1)) AS  '" . $row['NAME'] . "' ";
        $cstores = $cstores . "'" . $row['NAME'] . "', " ;

    }
?>

<!--https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

  function drawChart1() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', <?php echo $cstores ?>],
    <?php 

        $sql = "SELECT
                QUOTE(DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted,'%b-%y')) AS 'Month'
                ". $select ."
            FROM data 
            WHERE store_list IN (" . $user_stores . ")
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_submitted), MONTH(date_submitted)
            ORDER BY YEAR(date_submitted) ASC, MONTH(date_submitted) ASC";

        $Sat = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        foreach( $Sat as $key => $array ) {
            echo("[");
            foreach( $array as $attribute => $value ) {
                echo $value. ",";
            }
            echo("],");
        }
    ?>
```